# (firebase_analytics) Android: Not working in Android Flutter App

Tags: flutter, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

**[Now Problem]**

It is seen that the analytics data (e.g. user_engagement, first_open event...) are **automatically being collected for the iOS app, but not for the Android app.**

Except for firebase_analytics, all other Firebase APIs (firebase_auth, firebase_storage, firebase_messaging) work normally on both iOS and Android.

**[Firebase.initializeApp code in main.dart]**

```
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
```

);

even though I remove options and use only Firebase.initializeApp(); data still not collected.

**[pubspec.yaml]**

```
dependencies:
  firebase_core: ^2.15.0
  firebase_analytics: ^10.4.5 
  firebase_auth: ^4.7.2
  firebase_storage: ^11.2.5
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.5
  firebase_app_check: ^0.1.5+1
```

Comment: Now I'm facing with the same issue. Have u resolve it?